# Current Electricity (Resistors)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

now I know  "R=ρl⁄a"

and my doubt is would the area be a=l×l or a=l×t??

Comment: $A$ is the cross-sectional area through which the current is flowing in the two conductors in either case -- i.e. the area of the plates A and B. Knowing this, what do you think the expression for $A$ should be?

Comment: Current will be flowing through the dark surface

Comment: @Yejus  Ya I get it now the area should be a=l*t. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @Yuvraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area in this expression refers to area of cross section.

Cross section area means area perpendicular to **direction** of flow of current.Current flows from A to B.Perpendicular to this is the shaded area.

---

Fun fact (assuming you are new to the subject) -- Notice that I wrote **direction** of current.But current is scalar,isn't? Try and find how does that go around.

Comment: Ya I know current is scalar but isn't the velocity of electrons a vector? I guess that's why is it?

Comment: Well electric current is just like water current (that is one of the reasons behind its name "current").At basic level,you know pressure is scalar as it is defined as force normal to area. Electric current is similar. As it is always defined normal to area,it adds like a scalar quantity(similar to pressure).That is the reason why it is a scalar . Try and read scalar/vector definitions again.Notice the phrase "must add like vectors" in vector definition . This condition is not followed by current and hence it is scalar despite having the sense of direction.